# switching the place of x and y axis data in r

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector of data which consists of 20,000 numbers ranging between 0 and 1, i want to plot this data where x axis is the number values and y axis is  their frequencies.

```
         |
     Freq|
         |
         |
         |______________
              values
```

but when i use plot(vector) in R, it shows frequency on x axis named as index  and number values on y.
In the arguments used by plot() function i couldn't find anything helpful.
does anybody know how i could do this?

Comment: how about `plot(table(vector))`

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, it worked. And just one more question, do you know how i can remove outliers from a list of vector? in other words, removing the numbers which are placed in the last 2% of data from the mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a plot of frequencies, the best type of plot to make would be a barplot and the easiest way to make a barplot is just to pass a `table` to `barplot()`. For example

```
barplot(table(vector))
```

or if you just want a needle-style plot

```
plot(table(vector))
```

would also work.

If you want to trim outliers from the table, you could try

```
barplot( table( vector[vector<quantile(vector, .98)] ) )
```

here we drop samples that are above the 98% quantile.